# Functions inside conditionals

Tags: coding-style, language-agnostic

Is it a poor idea for readability or maintainability to use functions in conditionals as in the following example?

```
if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destinationFile)) {
    // Do work
}
```

Versus the more verbose

```
$moveFileSuccessful = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destinationFile);
if ($moveFileSuccessful) {
    // Do work
}
```

This is PHP, but the question applies to all languages.

Comment: what language is this, [tag:php]?

Comment: Yes, but the question should be language agnostic.

Comment: @gnat, that seems fairly specific to c# .net coding standards document suggestions, than functions in general. Also, the lack of the keyword functions make that difficult for future visitors with questions about functions in conditionals to find that question.

Comment: but you said you believe it's language agnostic, meaning you expect approaches to be the same for any language

Comment: @gnat If I stumbled upon that question, it's seems to be asking about the style standard guide Lance Hunt wrote for C# first and foremost. Yes, that likely answers the question, but I think it's not a good canonical.

Comment: Nevertheless, I'm voting to close anyway.  The answer over there says in its entirety what I would have said here.